# Anchor: How can I check specific Anchor Error Codes are caught in my test script if they are expected?

Tags: anchor, testing, anchor-test, error-handling

I have the following setName function and Name error code setup in my script as:

```
    pub fn set_name(
        ctx: Context<Name>,
        name: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        if name.chars().count() > 10 {
            return Err(ErrorCode::NameTooLong.into())
        }
        ctx.accounts.user.name = name;
        Ok(())
    }

#[error_code]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    #[msg("Name must be less than 10 characters")]
    NameTooLong,
}
```

And in my test script, if a user tries to set a name longer than 10 characters I want to check that exact error code is thrown... but I am not sure how to import the Anchor error codes from my program (the last line in the code below).

```
  it('User cannot set a name longer than 10 characters', async () => {
    let error = null;
    try {
      const tx = await program.rpc.setName(
        "a really long name that is way more than 10 characters",
        {
          accounts: {
            user: user.publicKey,
          },
          signers: [user],
        });
      await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(tx, "confirmed");
    } catch (e) {
      error = e;
    }
    // assert.equal(error, NameTooLong); // TODO: check for the right error
  });
```

1. How can I import NameTooLong and check against it?
2. How can I check against other generic Anchor error codes if expected? (e.g. missing signer or 0x0 custom program error)
3. Does this follow best practices for how to check errors are caught as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the general way of testing against errors in Anchor TS

```
it('Expects Error', async () => {
    try {
          const tx = await program.methods.testErr().rpc();
          assert.ok(false);
        } catch (_err) {
          assert.isTrue(_err instanceof AnchorError);
          const err: AnchorError = _err;
          const errMsg =
            "This is an error message clients will automatically display";
          assert.strictEqual(err.error.errorMessage, errMsg);
          assert.strictEqual(err.error.errorCode.number, 6000);
        }
});
```

You can read more on how to use Errors from the Anchor repo's test folder  [errors example](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/errors), which includes interacting and testing against various kinds of errors in Anchor and Solana.