# Unable to Utilize AnchorError in TS Tests

Tags: anchor, sendtransactionerror

I should be able to test my errors against *AnchorError* codes in my TS tests ([Ref](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1595/anchor-how-can-i-check-specific-anchor-error-codes-are-caught-in-my-test-script/1619#1619)), but when I run my tests are not working as expected and unable to recognize the *AnchorError*.

Here's my snippet:

```
    const someInstruction = await program.methods.doSomething()
        .accounts({
            user: user.publicKey,
        })
        .instruction();

    const transaction = new Transaction()
        .add(computeInstruction)
        .add(someInstruction);
```

My assertions that aren't working even though the tx is throwing as expected.

```
    try {
      const signature = await anchor.web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(program.provider.connection, transaction, [user]);
     } catch (_err) {
      assert.isTrue(_err instanceof AnchorError);
      const err: AnchorError = _err;
      const errMsg = "My Anchor Error";
      assert.strictEqual(err.error.errorMessage, errMsg);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is how I'm sending the transaction. Though, there is nothing wrong with how I'm sending my transaction, I'm was sending my transaction using the `@solana/web3.js` method, `sendAndConfirmTransaction`-- therefore the error type I'm getting back is a *SendTransactionError*.

If you want to use *AnchorError* in your testing, you will need to use Anchor's method for sending the transaction to the cluster, `.rpc()`, like so:

```
    try {
        await program.methods.doSomething()
        .accounts({
            user: user.publicKey,
        }).signers([user])
        .preInstructions([computeInstruction])
        .rpc();
    } catch (_err) {
      assert.isTrue(_err instanceof AnchorError);
      const err: AnchorError = _err;
      const errMsg = "My Anchor Error";
      assert.strictEqual(err.error.errorMessage, errMsg);
    }
```

Note that I am still able to append `computeInstruction` using the `.preInstructions()` method.